# SQL: Select All Rows for an ID if a Condition is Met

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table ("my_table"):

```
  student_id year scholarship gpa
1        111 2010         yes   5
2        111 2011         yes   4
3        111 2012          no   4
4        222 2010          no   4
5        222 2015         yes   5
6        222 2020         yes   7
7        333 2010         yes   6
8        333 2011          no   4
9        333 2012          no   4
```

**My Question:** If in 2010, a student had a scholarship and a gpa >=5 , then I want to select all available rows for that student. In this example, student 111 and student 333 will be selected.

I tried to do this two different ways:

**1) Using JOINS:**

```
WITH eligible_students AS (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE year = 2010 AND scholarship = 'yes' AND gpa >= 5
)
SELECT my_table.*
FROM my_table
JOIN eligible_students
ON my_table.student_id = eligible_students.student_id;
```

**2) Using the IN statement:**

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE student_id IN (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE year = 2010 AND scholarship = 'yes' AND gpa >= 5
);
```

**Both of these approaches produce the correct answer - but I am worried that perhaps this is only a coincidence. In general, is one of these methods a "safer" approach?**

Thanks!

Comment: 2nd one is what I would use - it is correct (not a coincidence) and it avoids the join stuff which IMHO is ugly and error prone... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @juanpethes the inner join can handle billions of rows, but IN get slow with big number of rows and there are limited elements possible

Comment: You are probably right. Sometimes the most "elegant" or simple solution is not always the best. Good point with the scalability. +1

Comment: @ nbk and @ juanpethes: thank you so much for your replies! Just to clarify - are both answers that I provided correct? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your usage I would neither use a self-join or an `in` predicate, this is almost always best implemented using *exists* which at worst will have the same performance as a join but in most cases will be more performant.

```
select *
from my_table t
where exists (
    select * from my_table t2
    where t2.student_id = t.student_id
    and t2.year = 2010 and t2.scholarship = 'yes' and t2.gpa >= 5
);
```

Comment: that is only viable, when you don't bneed the columns of the other table so you **would** use a join

Comment: There is no joined table in this scenario @nbk

Comment: @Stu: Thank you so much for your answer! Unfortunately, the WHERE EXIST function is not available in Netezza :(

Comment: Since there WHERE EXISTS function is not available - do you think what I have done is correct? thank you so much!

Comment: I've never used Netezza so assumed it would have the standard sql operators; in which case either of your existing options is fine - remember SQL is a declarative language, you don't tell the engine *how* to get your data only what data you want.